# DDK doesn't recognize DNDIS630, but it does recognize DNDIS620? (Windows NDIS)

Tags: wdk, ndis

I am trying to build an NDIS driver using DDK build Environment, the version is 7600.16385
The problem is that when i change my source file from DNDIS620=1 to DNDIS630=1, in order to switch to NDIS 6.3, it doesn't recognize it and therefore it gives me thousands of error.

Does the DDK support NDIS 6.3? Why it doesn't recognize DNDIS630?

I haven't moved it to WDK because using DDK worked so far and i don't know which parts of the code i need to change in order for it to be compatible with WDK? Plus it seems to much work to move to WDK, so i try to use DDK unless i really have to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for including the version number. 7600.16385 is the Windows 7 DDK, which did not support NDIS 6.30. The highest NDIS version supported by Windows 7 is NDIS 6.20.

If at all possible, please update to a newer WDK. Not only will that allow you to target newer operating systems, but in some cases, newer WDKs even improve your driver's behavior on older operating systems. Microsoft generally recommends using the newest WDK that contains support all the operating systems you must target.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jeffrey, updating to WDK solved the problem.